# Drivers for Classes in Java “Rectangle"

Tags: java, class, methods, instantiation, mutators

I’ve never used a separate file for a driver in Java.  I’m used to just using a main method.  I’ve used separate files in Python but Java is new.  Below is my code for each class (“Rectangle” and “Driver”), each from separate files.

Update with the methods changed to static:  Don’t pay attention to the change in class names or formatting…I’m just tweaking so it will work with MyProgrammingLab.  I still have to add in parameters for length and width being between 0.0 and 20.0 only (easy if-else statements).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Driver{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter length of rectangle:");
    double length = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter width of rectangle:");
    double width = input.nextDouble();

    Rectangle  Perimeter = new Rectangle(length, width);
    Perimeter.getPerimeter();
    Rectangle  Area = new Rectangle(length, width);
    Area.getArea();

    System.out.printf("Area: %.1f, Perimeter: %.1f",Rectangle.getArea(),Rectangle.getPerimeter());

}
```

}

final class Rectangle {

```
private static double mLength;
private static double mWidth;

public Rectangle(double length, double width){
    mLength = length;
    mWidth = width;
}   
public double getLength(){
    return mLength;
}

public double getWidth(){
    return mWidth;
}

public static double getArea(){
    double area = mWidth*mLength;
    return area;    
}
public static double getPerimeter(){
    double perimeter = (mWidth*2)+(mLength*2);
    return perimeter;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default constructor is provided by compiler if there are no constructor written explicitly.

But if you explicitly write any constructor in the class, then whenever you call a constructor, be it no-argument or with arguments, it will always look for explicitly defined constructor in class.

And, this is logically correct since, if you want to block creation of objects without any data in it, adding a constructor with argiment is the way to go.

So either explicitly write a no argument constructor in Rectangle and use setter to set its attributs, or just use the argument constructor in your method.

---

**Add to Rectangle.class an empty constructor :**

```
public Rectangle() {

}
```

**Or Use constructor declared with parameters in your method**

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(length, width);
```

---

In your case you are using the rectangle object wrong.
I think what you looking to do is this :

```
Rectangle  rectangle = new Rectangle(length , width );
System.out.printf("Area: %.1f, Perimeter: %.1f",rectangle.getArea() ,rectangle.getPerimeter());
```

Comment: Or, if you can, remove the setters and pass the arguments to the constructor calls

Comment: I’m receiving Formatter errors when I tried both of those options. Any advice? Do you need more to go off of than just that...

Comment: I tested it without my “printf”.  It is trying to print Area and Perimeter's memory location instead of the actual value.  I deleted my setters and passed the arguments instead, but not sure why it’s printing that output. Example: Area:Rectangle@211d0a4f Perimeter: Rectangle@798fd984

Comment: It's printing default toString() method, which is the reference of the Rectangle object.

I think what you wanna do is : `Rectangle  rectangle = new Rectangle(length , width );

 System.out.printf("Area: %.1f, Perimeter: %.1f",rectangle.getArea() ,rectangle.getPerimeter());`

Comment: can I concatenate that when I call Area.getArea() somehow?

Comment: The way your code work Area is just a rectangle with no length of width. Also what do you mean by concatenate ?

Comment: Do you mean : `System.out.printf("Area: " + rectangle.getArea() + ", Perimeter: " + rectangle.getPerimeter());`

Comment: Oh I got it! Perfect!  Is concatenate the wrong word?  Area.getArea().toString();

Comment: For info in java you want your variable name to start with a lowercase.
Also calling your rectangle Area seems missleading. And I'm not sure what you are trying to acheve with the toString there exactly ?

Comment: It was just something I had seen a professor do in passing during a class.  I’d never actually used it like that before.  I used your code above (and javaguy) and it works but I had to change my methods to static before it would work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, maybe you can update your ode so we can see what's up.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to **create a `Rectangle` object with it's length & width, so use your overloaded  `Rectangle` constructor** by passing the `length` and `width` arguments (entered by user) as shown below:

```
Rectangle  Perimeter = new Rectangle(length, width);
```

> the constructor Rectangle() is undefined. Can anyone help?

The important point is that when you have an overloaded constructor like in your `Rectangle` class (where there are no default i.e., no argument constructors written), **you can't create an object using `new Rectangle();`, this is because compiler doesn't add the default constrcutor automatically** for you. I suggest look [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257938/why-is-there-no-default-constructor-generated-if-you-define-an-explicit-construc) for more details on this.

Also, if you wanted to print the `Rectangle` object with `length` & `width` details, you need to `override` `toString()` method from `java.lang.Object` method as shown below:

```
public class Rectangle {

    private double mLength;

    private double mWidth;

    //add your code here as is

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangle [mLength=" + mLength + ", mWidth=" + mWidth + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestion as it was the same as TheBakker down below..If you have any advice for my printing output as well, I’d appreciate it!  See the comment on his thread...

Comment: Thanks…I got it but I had to change my getArea and getPerimeter to static.  Doesn’t seem to cause any issues, but can you explain why?